# Shiro 404 not found issue after login

Tags: jersey, http-status-code-404, shiro

I am using Shiro with Jersey in a REST API. I am using the form based authentication since I need to send from my angular app a post message in order to authenticate (username, password). There is no jsp nor other page, just the filter and corresponding realm.

I am having following configuration: I have my custom FormAuthenticationFilter, let's say MyFormAuthenticationFilter. Then, in configureShiroWeb I have 
`addFilterChain("/login", Key.get(MyFormAuthenticationFilter.class));`

When I access the /login path with correct credentials sent with post request for the first time, I get logged in. So far so good. The problem is that when I log in successfully and try to access the /login path again, then I get 404. I understand that there's no resource under this path, but is it possible to somehow make it return no content in case I am already logged in?

Thanks
BR

Comment: what do you mean, "return no content", a 404 status is http's way to let the browser know there is no content.

Comment: by no content I mean 201. 404 is "not found".

Comment: My mistake, I mean to return 204 No Content. But nevermind, just change the return code not to be 404.